# How does reading nested objects in custom serialisation work?

Tags: java, serialization

Assume the scenario below.

Ignore the lack of a `serialVersionUID`. This is just example code.

```
class A implements Serializable {

    int test;
    B b;

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        s.writeInt(test);
        s.writeObject(b);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException {
        this.test = s.readInt();
        this.b = (B) s.readObject(); // <-- HERE
    }
}

class B implements Serializable {

    // some fields here

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException 
    {/* this doesn't matter */}

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException 
    {/* this doesn't matter */}
}
```

I'd like to know how (or if) the line marked with "HERE" actually makes sense (or why it doesn't).

How does the JVM know that it is supposed to use `B`'s custom read method in order to unserialise `B`? Surely, it doesn't?

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: ObjectInputStream doesn't care what object it's reading, it calls readObject on the ObjectInputStream, not B's specific implementation.

Comment: Same way it knew to use A's custom method. Your case is just a recursion.

Comment: @kolsyrad but how does it read the object and know when to stop etc?

Comment: Wikipedia actually explains this quite well @Lolums:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Comment: @kolsyrad Your Wikipedia citation doesn't explain any such thing. Custom serialization methods aren't even mentioned let alone explained. In any case the place to look is the Object Serialization Specificiation.